# How to call action whitout reloading page, i need to delete some row

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

```
public function populateImageGrid(){

    $html = '';
    $result = $this->_db->select('
        SELECT m.*
        FROM '.$this->_table.' as m order by id desc'
    );

    if($result == true) {
        foreach($result as $row) {

            $parse = explode('/',$row['title']);
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize(substr($row['title'],1));    

            $html= $html.'
            <div class="image_item" >
                <img class="hvr-ripple-out" src="'.$row["title"].'"  />

                <div class="image_item_desc">
                    <h5><span style="color: rgb(49, 157, 181);"><b>Naziv slike:</b></span>  '.ucfirst($parse[3]).'</h5>
                    <h5><span style="color: rgb(49, 157, 181);"><b>Relativna adresa slike:</b></span>  '.$row["title"].'</h5>
                    <h5><span style="color: rgb(49, 157, 181);"><b>Originalne dimenzije slike:</b></span> width: '.$width.'px,   height: '.$height.'px</h5>
                    <a href="#" onclick="deleteImage('.$row["id"].')" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Izbriši</a>
                </div>
                <div class="image_action"></div>
            </div>';

        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

This is written code in the apphp framework. 
This is my function which populates view with my image, I need to add functionality to delete that images, but without reloading.
I want to add action delete to my button and preform that without reloading page.

Comment: maybe ajax will help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the image from the webpage (from the html), jQuery is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I cant use jquery because my jquery ajax request was blocked by framework. I need difrent solution